# How can list AWS ENI's with a certain "Description" with AWS cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

When I execute:

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --region=us-east-1 \
--query="NetworkInterfaces[*].[Description, NetworkInterfaceId]" \
--output text \
--filter 'Name=Description,Values=ELB*'
```

I get this error message:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the DescribeNetworkInterfaces operation:
The filter 'Description' is invalid
```

I am trying to list my ENI's that have a description that starts with "ELB".

UPDATE: Thanks jordanm your suggestion has stopped the error message but I still think I doing something wrong with my filter option.  If I execute:

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --region=us-east-1 \
--query="NetworkInterfaces[*].[Description, NetworkInterfaceId]" \
--output text | grep "^ELB"
```

I get results, but if I try to filter with `--filter 'Name=Description,Values=ELB*'` instead of `| grep "^ELB"` I do not get any results.

Comment: `--filters Name=tag:Description,Values=ELB*`

Comment: @jordanm that does remove the error message but I get zero results.  I guess there is something wrong with the `Values=ELB*' part of my command.  How should I specify a wildcard?

Comment: That's correct values that start with `EBS`. If you want contains EBS, use `*EBS*`

Comment: I should probably point out that the "Description" I am talking about is not a tag.

Answer (score 0):

The following should get you ENI's whose description begin with 'EBS'

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --region=us-east-1 \
--query="NetworkInterfaces[?starts_with(Description, 'EBS')].[Description, NetworkInterfaceId]" \
--output text
```

You can change the literal 'EBS' to whatever value you want to check for in the description. If you want to do a check where the Description contains 'EBS' not just begins with it, you can use the following command

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --region=us-east-1 \
--query="NetworkInterfaces[?contains(Description, 'EBS')].[Description, NetworkInterfaceId]" \
--output text
```